# Arrays without fixed length in golang

Tags: go

I have recently started with `golang` and was working with `arrays` and came across a situation where I did not have the number of elements. Is there a way to initialize a array without a size and then append elements in the end? Something like there in other programming languages like `c++`, `javascript` where there are `vectors` and `arrays` that can be used and we can add elements by functions like `push_back` or `push`. Is there a way that we can do this or is there a library in which we can do this? Thank you!

Comment: Please take the tour of go to learn the basics of the language, [slices](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7) are covered right after arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `slice` for your purpose.

```golang
array := make([]int, 0)
array = append(array, 1)
array = append(array, 2)
```

Here, array is a slice of `int` type data and initially of size `0`. You can append `int` type data by `append(array, <int-type-data>)`.

Answer (score 15):

```
a := []int{}
a = append(a, 4)
fmt.Println(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

With Golang, Arrays always have a fixed length:

> In Go, an array is a numbered sequence of elements of a specific length.

(Source: https://gobyexample.com/arrays)

If you want the flexibility of a variable length, you'll probably want to use a Slice instead:

> Slices are a key data type in Go, giving a more powerful interface to sequences than arrays.

(Source: https://gobyexample.com/slices)

[This post on the go blog](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) (though old) has a nice overview of the two data types.